# Permission denied when running Reac Native app

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm currently using Ubuntu as OS and I'm trying to run a React Native app using ngrok tunneling and it keep giving me some kind of permission error:

```
Failed to construct transformer:  Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/tmp/metro-file-map-ed9a6bfb51f4bf256a1cfc72b795cb1f-b3b4765b187f9b83f2ce1adec68ebd1f'

at Object.openSync (node:fs:581:18)

at writeFileSync (node:fs:2365:35)

at DiskCacheManager.write (node_modules/metro-file-map/src/cache/DiskCacheManager.js:54:37)

at FileMap._takeSnapshotAndPersist (node_modules/metro-file-map/src/index.js:537:30)

at node_modules/metro-file-map/src/index.js:215:20

at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
errno: -13,
code: 'EACCES',
syscall: 'open',
path: '/tmp/metro-file-map-ed9a6bfb51f4bf256a1cfc72b795cb1f- 
b3b4765b187f9b83f2ce1adec68ebd1f'
}
```

I tried running:

sudo chmod -R 777 path/to/file

sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm

sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config

as a teacher of mine suggested but it didn't work